# Exporting combined data/charts to a single PDF from a ASP.NET web app

Tags: asp.net, pdf, reporting, charts, export-to-pdf

We have a ASP.NET C# web application and are trying to find a way to combine data/tables and charts that can be exported a single PDF.

Some things we're looking for...

1. The ability to export a single PDF
   that includes charts, tables, etc.
2. The ability to embed the report into
   the web app
3. A good number of highly configurable
   chart types

Tools we have...

We have [.netCharting](http://dotnetcharting.com/), which has the option to display the embedded reports as PDF, but that's per chart, which would mean multiple PDFs for a page with multiple charts and no custom tables or anything included in that PDF. We do like the variety of chart types and the versatility to make more complex reports, though. .netCharting includes the charts we could use.

We also have [LogiXML Ad Hoc](http://www.logixml.com/products/ad-hoc-reporting.html) reporting, which does allow you to combine different charts and data into a single, exportable PDF, but it doesn't offer very complex charts. Also, as far as I can tell, it doesn't allow you to dynamically display a report by passing parameters from your web app, which would be necessary.

We've considered trying to interact with Excel (through COM) on the server to produce what we need.

Are there any tools out there that combine the strengths of our existing tools?

Answer (score 1):

I Use dundas and work fine. just try the trial, and see if that workd for you.

See ya.

Answer (score 1):

We use DevExpress XtraReports for just what you're describing.  Pretty charts, not difficult to learn and not expensive.